# Published app crashes

Tags: c#

I created a wpf app that works fine, I build my app on release. but when I publish the app it crashes, why?

Here published files:

[image]

When I click the app:

[image]

Any ideas?

Here view problems details output:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
>     Problem Signature 01: PreparationToolApp.exe
>     Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
>     Problem Signature 03: 5b6c0cb3
>     Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
>     Problem Signature 05: 4.7.3130.0
>     Problem Signature 06: 5b175e25
>     Problem Signature 07: 1679
>     Problem Signature 08: fc
>     Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
>     OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: 5861
>     Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
>     Additional Information 3: 9044
>     Additional Information 4: 904415419f02c4ad4d39c4867383d25a
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>     C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: View the problem details and debug it

Comment: Click the [View problem details] and post the output. There are literally unlimited things that could be wrong you need to show the error as we can't guess

Comment: This can have thousands of resons, consider adding a logger or starting the application with a debugger (or just click _Debug the program_).

Comment: The thing is the the app works fine if I run it from `...\bin\release\myapp.exe` only the published version doesn't work

Comment: if you try to make a [mcve] you will probably encounter additional information relevant to your problem.

Comment: Related [microsoft forms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/729ee339-a9ba-47a8-b161-089743de9fce/installation-and-run-issues-with-deployed-wpf-app?forum=wpf) and possible duplicate [in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746064/error-in-running-wpf-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get useful WPF .NET error information from a user's machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376028/how-can-i-get-useful-wpf-net-error-information-from-a-users-machine)

Comment: @bradbury9 firs link is broken

Comment: Hi @exe, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If this app works fine in debug mode You should begin from checking differences between *debug* and *release* configurations. For example: You can use such directive:

```
#if DEBUG

#else

#endif
```

to obtain different paths, constants and other values only for debug mode. After switching to release mode You might bring into front improper values, which were not tested in debug mode.

Comment: there is no info in the question that leads to Release working fine, only that Publish does not. With the lack of info the OP provides this answer could or could not solve the problem. I would have put it as an answer.

Comment: Then this question does not address the problem. @exe You should consider adding extra info on the question of the structure of the project. The error message refers to "problem signature" and you provide no info whatsoever about the program being signed, or if the certificate used to sign it validates OK.

Comment: @bradbury9 that's wpf app with some class library's. that's the structure, that's irrelevant

Comment: I would bet on missing dependencies on the deployed/published version (according MS forum linked in question comments), but with no info whatsoever on the external dlls and if they are present on the deployment enviroment its hard to tell.

Comment: @bradbury9 I think That's the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177716/discussion-between-bradbury9-and-exe).