# Crashing deployed app on XamlParse

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I have created a ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest from my WPF application but when I try to install it, this crashes and I get the following error log:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   phynix.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   54b90fb3
Problem Signature 04:   mscorlib
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.17929
Problem Signature 06:   4ffa561c
Problem Signature 07:   43c4
Problem Signature 08:   105
Problem Signature 09:   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1031
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Someone knows what is the problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XamlParse` exception means the XAML can't be read or the code generated from it can't be executed correctly.

Usually this is:

- An image file that isn't included as resource in the project, or in a location that isn't available on the deployment machine;
- Missing referenced assemblies and/or their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking up an `UnhandledException` event in `WPF`, and add the event hookup in your `app.xaml` in order to avoid the above exception.

Reference: [How can I get useful WPF .NET error information from a user's machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376028/)

Comment: avoid? I don't think hooking UnhandledException will "avoid" the exception. It can be used to log the exception however if you mean that.